# Failing to lock file caused by denied access (rust / cargo)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When I use `cargo run` I get this error:

```
warning: unused manifest key: package.author
error: failed to lock file: C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Work\Coding\melb_os\Cargo.lock

Caused by:
  Denied Access. (os error 5)
```

I'm using rustc 1.57.0-nightly on a windows machine. My antivirus popped a warning when I ran the code. I had compiled the program before and didn't get any problems, but this time it happened and doesn't seem to work anymore.
I disabled the antivirus, added rustc to the path, tried to run it with other IDE, but changed nothing.

Comment: "*My antivirus popped a warning when I ran the code*"—what did the warning say?

Comment: I don't remember clearly, but said something about a possible malicious action. But it was just a warning, the antivirus didn't block anything

Comment: The permissions on `Cargo.lock` are wrong. selecting it in Explorer and setting the owner to your self in the permissions should fix it

Comment: Your antivirus will probably have logged that warning somewhere that you can review it.

Comment: Changed the permissions and still won't work.

Comment: I fiddled around my antivirus and I found that a while ago it blocked rustc-nightly actions and I didn't see. I was able to white list it now. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the log where Norton blocked rustc-nightly without my knowledge and white listed it. If you have this problem just enter your anti-virus history and look for the log of the action, then you can undo it.